# past perfect for stop

Tags: past-perfect

Friday morning and after the rain that bothered us the night before **had stopped** we wandered in the record stores of Madrid where literally tons of records were waiting for us.

why had stopped?
Wednesday night the rain began and bothered us then it stopped on friday morning and we wandered in the streets of Madrid. So "stopped" is after "bothered" so why past perfect, is it to tell the reader that the rain began  first and it bothered us  quite a long time after .

Comment: We wandered after the rain had stopped.

Answer (score 1):

**Had stopped** is used since the rain **started** and then **stopped**, both in the past. Presumably, the rain that **bothered** you continued to **bother** you for the entire duration of its raining, so :

> Friday morning...after the rain...**had stopped**, we wandered...

The phrase :

> ...**that bothered us**...

is an **adjective phrase** describing the rain, not when you were **bothered**.